# Не компилируется изменения в подключенном файле

Tags: less

```
`@import "grid.less";

.reset();

#wrapper {
    .wrapper();
}
#main {
    display: flex;
}
`
```

Вопрос: Все работает корректно, но когда вносишь изменения в подключенный файл   Grid.less, gulp не компилирует эти изменения в основной css.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить этот файл в ваш Gulp Watch. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch('./less/grid.less', function() { gulp.start('less') });
});
```